# NumPy chained comparison with two predicates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-expression

In NumPy, I can generate a boolean array like this:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9])
>>> arr > 2
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

How can we chain comparisons together? For example:

```
>>> 6 > arr > 2
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  False,  False], dtype=bool)
```

Attempting to do so results in the error message

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: FYI, [PEP 535](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0535/) proposes to make this possible in python 3.7.

Comment: PEP 535 still has status deferred in 2023 :|

Answer (score 27, accepted):

AFAIK the closest you can get is to use `&`, `|`, and `^`:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9])
>>> (2 < arr) & (arr < 6)
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> (2 < arr) | (arr < 6)
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> (2 < arr) ^ (arr < 6)
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

I don't think you'll be able to get `a < b < c`-style chaining to work.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the numpy logical operators to do something similar.

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9])
>>> arr > 2
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>>np.logical_and(arr>2,arr<6)
Out[5]: array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Equivalent to `&` which I prefer

Answer (score 4):

Chained comparisons are not allowed in numpy. You need to write both left and right comparisons separately, and chain them with [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). Also you'll need to parenthesise both expressions due to [operator precendence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) (`|`, `&` and `^` have a higher precedence). In this case, since you want both conditions to be satisfied you need an bitwise AND (`&`):

```
(2<arr) & (arr<6)
# array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False])
```

---

It was actually proposed to make this possible in [PEP 535](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0535/), though it still remains deferred. In it there is an explanation on why this occurs. As posed in the question, chaining comparisons in such way, yields:

```
2<arr<6
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
> Use a.any() or a.all()

The problem here, is that python is internally expanding the above to:

```
2<arr and arr<6
```

Which is what causes the error, since `and` is implicitly calling `bool`, and `NumPy` only permits implicit coercion to a boolean value for single elements (not arrays with `size>1`), since a boolean array with many values does not evaluate neither to `True` or `False`. It is due to this ambiguity that this isn't allowed, and evaluating an array in boolean context always yields a `ValueError`

Comment: Thank you for this updated answer! I wish the proposal was accepted