# What does it mean that Python comparison operators chain/group left to right?

Tags: python, comparison, operator-precedence, associativity

The Python documentation for [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) states:

> Operators in the same box group left to right (except for
>   comparisons, including tests, which all have the same precedence and
>   chain from left to right — see section [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)...)

What does this mean?  Specifically:

1. *"Operators in the same box group left to right (except for
   comparisons...)"* -- do comparisons *not* group left to right?
2. If comparisons do *not* group left to right, what do they do instead? Do they "chain" as opposed to "group"?
3. If comparisons "chain" rather than "group", what is the difference between "chaining" and "grouping"?
4. What would be some examples to demonstrate that the comparison operators chain from left to right rather than from right to left?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Grouping (this is what non-comparison operators do):

```
a + b + c   means   (a + b) + c
```

Chaining (this is what comparison operators do):

```
a < b < c   means   (a < b) and (b < c)
```

Grouping left to right (this is the way things are grouped):

```
5 - 2 - 1   means   (5 - 2) - 1 == 2
```

as opposed to grouping right to left (this would produce a different result):

```
5 - (2 - 1) == 4
```

**Chaining left to right**

Chaining is left to right, so in `a < b < c`, the expression `a < b` is evaluated before `b < c`, and if `a < b` is falsey, `b < c` is not evaluated.

`(2 < 1 < f())` gives the value `False` without calling the function `f`, because `2 < 1` evaluates to false, so the second comparison does not need to be performed.

`f() > 1 > g()` calls `f()` in order to evaluate the first comparison, and depending on the result, it might or might not need to evaluate the second condition, which requires calling `g()`.

NB. Each operand is evaluated at most once. So in the expression `1 < f() < 2`, the function `f()` is only called once, and the value it gives is used in both comparisons (if necessary).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Thanks @khelwood, that's helpful!  That's a good example showing how grouping left-to-right differs from right-to-left.  I'm looking for a similar chaining example to show how chaining left-to-right differs from right-to-left.  If it chained right-to-left, then would  `a < b < c` mean `(b < c) and (a < b)` ?

Comment: `True > False == False` this code give `True` as result. but if you apply Chaining left to right, it should give `False`.

Comment: @suryasingh `True > False` is true. `False==False` is true. So `True > False == False` is true.

Comment: @khelwood got it. i misunderstand it. i though it is `True > False` gives True than True == False will give False. Now got it. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Something is wrong here `(True > False)` → `True`, so you have `True == False` → `False`.  Alternatively, if it were: `True > (False == False)` → `True > True` → `False`, so in both cases it should be `False`, never `True`

Comment: @juanfal No, because comparison operators **chain**, as described in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the chain behavior is not so obvious.

```
a == b == c
```

although one would expect this to be converted to

```
a == b and b == c
```

it is in fact converted into somthing similar to

```
b == c if a == b else False
```

which is a bit confusing if one tries to override the behavior of the comparison operators and chain them.

Comment: More like `b == c if a == b else a == b` (except that `a==b` is only evaluated once). But that is also what `a==b and b==c` gives you, so they are equivalent.

Comment: `a == b == c` is indeed converted to `a == b and b == c` so I'm not sure how to interpret the first part of this answer. The behaviour of `and` and `or` in python is indeed slightly non-obvious, but chaining itself seems intuitive. For instance, `1 and 3` evaluates to 3; `0 and f(x)` evaluates to `0` without performing the `f(x)` call; `'hello' or f(x)` evaluates to `'hello'` without calling `f(x)`; `[] or False` evaluates to `[]`. Assuming `a == b` and `b == c` both returns booleans, which is the case for builtin types, then `a == b == c` also returns a boolean without any surprise.

Comment: Of course if `a`, `b` and `c` belong to a complicated class that redefines `==`, for instance a numpy array, then things could get weird. (Perhaps you could edit your answer to add an example of weird behaviour with numpy!!)

Comment: Actually numpy just prudently doesn't allow using boolean operators `and` and `or` on arrays, so trying to chain `==` on numpy arrays safely raises a `ValueError`: `np.array([1, 2, 3]) == np.array([0, 2, 3])
array([False,  True,  True])` but `np.array([1, 2, 3]) == np.array([0, 2, 3]) == np.array([0, 0, 3])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. See also [NumPy chained comparison with two predicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075324/numpy-chained-comparison-with-two-predicates)