# Precedence of chained comparisons?

Tags: python

I'm wondering how Python parses:

```
not a < b < c
```

It seems to interpret this as:

```
not (a < b < c)
```

as opposed to `(not a) < b < c`

This question explains grouping vs chaining:
[Python comparison operators chaining/grouping left to right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753474/python-comparison-operators-chaining-grouping-left-to-right) but what are the rules for the precedence of chained comparisons?

It's strange to me that `not`, `<` and `>` have the same precedence, but `not a < b < c` parses as `not (a < b < c)` while `-a < b < c` parses as `(-a) < b < c`.

I tested this by evaluating `not 2 > 1 > 2` in Python 2.7.

Comment: `not 2 < 1 < 2` isn't being parsed as `not (2 < 1 < 2)`. Each term is processed left-to-right. The `not 2` is `False` which is the same as the numeric value `0`—so it's equivalent to `0 < 1 < 2`.

Comment: This tips was already viewed. Could be:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753474/python-comparison-operators-chaining-grouping-left-to-right

Comment: What made you think `not`, `<`, and `>` had the same precedence?

Comment: @martineau I was using 2 > 1 > 2 not 2 < 1 < 2, and I don't think that's true about the parsing

Comment: @user2357112 I mistook the `not in` and `is not` tests for the boolean `not` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has an Abstract Syntax Tree module to show you what's happening:

```
import ast
t = ast.parse('not a < b < c')
print(ast.dump(t))
```

It gives (cleaned up a bit):

```
[Expr(value=UnaryOp(
    op=Not(),
    operand=Compare(
        left=Name(id='a'),
        ops=[Lt(), Lt()],
        comparators=[Name(id='b'), Name(id='c')]
    )
))]
```

And indeed, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) says that `not` has lower precedence than `<`.