# Conditional statement behave different in different language

Tags: python, c

In **C** programming, the following code block return **False**

```
int a=15, b=10,c=5;
    if(a>b>c)
    {
        printf("True");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("False");
    }
```

But in **Python**, the following block return **True**.

```
a = 15
b = 10
c = 5
if a > b > c:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

**Edit:** Found a solution from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753474/python-comparison-operators-chaining-grouping-left-to-right), it explain very well in python perspective. And in C programming perspective this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523652/conditional-statement-behave-different-in-different-language/52523694#52523694) explain my question very well.

Comment: C and Python books can explain. These are two different languages with different syntax and rules.

Comment: Another format of the same question: why this snippet does not compile in assembly?

Comment: C and Python are *very* different languages, with very different rules.  Do not assume that *any* operators behave the same way between the two languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They behave differently because that's how the languages are implemented.

With C, `a > b > c` is evaluated left to right. There is no concept of "operator chaining" (I'll get to this shortly), so the expression is evaluated as `(a > b) > c` which is `1 > c` which is `false` (in C, logical expressions either return 1 or 0).

In python, OTOH, `a > b > c` evaluates to `a > b and b > c` (as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) on comparisons), which turns out to be `True` in this case.