# Why is ‘==‘ coming before ‘in’ in Python?

Tags: python

The following code outputs False, when according to the Python Order of Operations it should output True (the order should be in -> ==, not the other way around). Why is == coming before in?

```
y = "33"
"3" in y == True
```

Output

```
False
```

Comment: the `in` and the `==`  operator have the same precedence. So they are evaluated from left to right I belive. Why not using `()` so it is clear in the code what do you want? `("3" in "33") == True `

Comment: Also, this is an instance of *operator chaining*, since `==` and `in` both count as comparison operators. So this is evaluated as `('3' in y) and (y == True)`

Comment: Also, you never need to compare with True or False. If correctly parenthesized, your statement would mean True == True or False == True

Comment: Also, why not simply write `3 in y`? there is no need to check a bool result against bool. You can read about [operator chaining here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753528/1918287)

Answer (score 18):

The existing answers give helpful advice that you shouldn't compare booleans to `True` because it's redundant. However, none of the answers actually answer the root question: "why does `"3" in y == True` evaluate to `False`?".

That question was answered in a comment by juanpa.arrivillaga:

> Also, this is an instance of *operator chaining*, since `==` and `in` both count as comparison operators. So this is evaluated as `('3' in y) and (y == True)`

In Python, comparison operators can be *chained*. For example, if you want to check that `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are increasing, you can write `a < b < c < d` instead of `a < b and b < c and c < d`. Similarly, you can check that they are all equal with `a == b == c == d`.

Chained comparisons are described in the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

Answer (score -2):

In python, comparisons, memberships tests and identity tests all have the same precedence.
The keyword `in` which checks for membership returns a `bool`, there is no need for extra compare with a second `bool`. However, you can group the expressions like so...

`y = "33"`

`("3" in y) == True`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "why does `"3" in y == True` evaluate to `False`?"