# if x in y == False: leads to surprising behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

A colleague of mine wrote something like the following:

```
list = [1,2,3]

m = 5;

if m in list == False:
  print("not in list")
else:
  print("in list")
```

This small test program will output:

```
"in list"
```

Which is sort of incorrect (not desired, anyway).

We know this isn't the pythonic way to write it (that would have been just write `not in` to see if it's in the list) - but even then we want to know what's going on as it is surprising behavior.

Note that:

```
if (m in list) == False:
```

is enough to fix it.

What's going on?

Comment: As to why the surprise, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412942/why-is-coming-before-in-in-python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that answers my question

Comment: Also, you should make sure not to use `list` as a variable name, since it shadows the built-in version.

Comment: Answer from jonrsharpe in short: `m in y == False` is equal to `(m in y) and (y == False)`