# In which order are two or more consecutive membership operators treated in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, membership

```
>>> g = [2, True, 5]
>>> print(2 in g in g)
False

>>> g.append(g)
>>> print(2 in g in g)
True
```

Why is the first snippet outputting `False` when there is `2` and 'True' both in the list?

Why is it outputting `True` after appending 'g' ?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753474/python-comparison-operators-chaining-grouping-left-to-right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [operator chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) and will expand to `1 in g and g in g`. So only after you append `g` to itself this becomes true.

You can use parentheses to get the behavior you want: `(1 in g) in g`. This forces the `1 in g` part to be evaluated first (however `in` compares for equality and `True == 1` so `True` doesn't need to be part of the list actually).

Answer (score 0):

It works on the principle of [operator chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)
So `print(1 in g in g)` is equivalent to
`print(1 in g and g in g)` resulting in

`False` (True and False)