# python comparison operator conflict

Tags: python

```
a=8
b=3
if a>b!=True:
    print("ex1")
else:
    print("ex2")
```

Output: `ex1`

Output expected: `ex2`

Why is the `else` condition not executed whether `a>b` gives `True` value?

Comment: `a > b != True` means `(a > b) and (b != True)`.

Comment: Note: Would be much easier to write `a <= b`...

Comment: More general explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753474/python-comparison-operators-chaining-grouping-left-to-right

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @khelwood has mentioned in comments.

You need to know the Operator Precedence before using operators together.

Please go through this: [Operator Precedence](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/operators_precedence_example.htm)

```
a=8
b=3
if (a>b) != True:
    print("ex1")
else:
    print("ex2")
```

Now the above code will give you `ex2` as output because `()` has a higher precedence.

Comment: By using `()` you override the operator precedence and operator chaining.

Answer (score 0):

You observed effect of [chaining feature of comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) which

```
a>b!=True
```

make meaning `a>b and b!=True`, to avoid summoning said feature use brackets, i.e.

```
(a>b)!=True
```

As side note that above condition might be expressed as

```
not (a>b)
```