# Why 3>2>1 returns True whereas (3>2)>1 returns False in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison-operators

I was not able to find proper documentation about it. Same thing I did in Javascript and I got False for Both Cases. I know that 3>2 should be treated as (3>2) -> True|1, therefore 3>2>1 is 1>1 which is false. It would be great if you could suggest some official documentation along with the explanation.

x = (3 > 2) > 1

print(x)

> False

y = 3 > 2 > 1

print(y)

> True

Comment: Because `(3 > 2) > 1` is `True > 1`.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 5):

Javascript is evaluating `3 > 2 > 1` as `(3 > 2) > 1`, so they are equivalent. In both cases, `3 > 2 > 1 -> true > 1 -> false`.

Python, however, features comparison chaining, so `3 > 2 > 1` means `3 > 2 and 2 > 1`. `(3 > 2) > 1` works the same way it does in JS. [Here's](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/) an article you can read to learn more. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753528/12162258) a high-quality answer on this site that explains the difference between operator grouping and chaining in python.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why 3>2>1 returns True whereas (3>2)>1 returns False in Python is because of the way that the comparison operators work in Python.

In the first example, 3>2>1, Python is interpreting this as (3>2) and (2>1). The first comparison 3>2 returns True, which is then compared to 2>1 which also returns True. Since both comparisons are True, the overall expression evaluates to True.

In the second example, (3>2)>1, Python is interpreting this as True>1. The comparison True>1 returns False as true is considered 1 and 1 is not greater than 1.

In Python, comparison operators return a Boolean value, True or False, rather than an integer value. When a Boolean value is used in a numeric context, such as a comparison, True is interpreted as 1 and False is interpreted as 0 , that's why the second example return False.