# Why doesn't chained (interval) comparison work on numpy arrays?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

`a < b < c` is an [chained expression](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) in Python, and it looks like it works on objects with appropriate comparison operators defined, but it doesn't work on numpy arrays. Why?

```
import numpy as np

class ContrarianContainer(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __le__(self, y):
        return not self.x <= y
    def __lt__(self, y):
        return not self.x < y
    def __ge__(self, y):
        return not self.x >= y
    def __gt__(self, y):
        return not self.x > y
    def __eq__(self, y):
        return not self.x == y
    def __ne__(self, y):
        return not self.x != y

numlist = np.array([1,2,3,4])
for n in numlist:
    print 0 < n < 3.5
for n in numlist:
    print 0 > ContrarianContainer(n) > 3.5
print 0 < numlist < 3.5
```

this prints:

```
True
True
True
False
True
True
True
False
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-187-277da7750148> in <module>()
      4 for n in numlist:
      5     print 0 < n < 3.5
----> 6 print 0 < numlist < 3.5

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy chain comparison with two predicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075324/numpy-chain-comparison-with-two-predicates)

Comment: Not a duplicate -- this question asks *why*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the docs say:

> Formally, if a, b, c, ..., y, z are expressions and op1, op2, ..., opN are comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

and

> (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

For a scalar

```
In [20]: x=5
In [21]: 0<x<10
Out[21]: True
In [22]: 0<x and x<10
Out[22]: True
```

But with an array

```
In [24]: x=np.array([4,5,6])    
In [25]: 0<x and x<10
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This ValueError arises when a numpy boolean is used in a context that expects a scalar boolean.

```
In [26]: (0<x)
Out[26]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [30]: np.array([True, False]) or True
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
In [33]: if np.array([True, False]): print('yes')
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It evaluates the `0<x`, but doesn't even get to evaluating the `x<10`, because it can't use the resulting boolean array in a `or/and` context. `numpy` has defined `|` and `&`, but not `or` or `and`.

```
In [34]: (0<x) & x<10
Out[34]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

When we use `0 < x <10` we are implicitly expecting to evaluate a vectorized version of the scalar chained expression.

```
In [35]: f = np.vectorize(lambda x: 0<x<10, otypes=[bool])
In [36]: f(x)
Out[36]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [37]: f([-1,5,11])
Out[37]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Note that attempting to apply chaining to a list doesn't even get past the first `<`:

```
In [39]: 0 < [-1,5,11]
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < list()
```

---

This set of expressions indicates that the `&` operator has precedence over the `<` operator:

```
In [44]: 0 < x & x<10
ValueError ...

In [45]: (0 < x) & x<10
Out[45]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [46]: 0 < x & (x<10)
Out[46]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [47]: 0 < (x & x)<10
ValueError...
```

So the safe version is  `(0 < x) & (x<10)`, making sure that all `<` are evaluated before the `&`.

### edit

Here's a further example that confirms the short-cut `and` evaluation:

```
In [53]: x=2
In [54]: 3<x<np.arange(4)
Out[54]: False
In [55]: 1<x<np.arange(4)
Out[55]: array([False, False, False,  True])
```

When `3<x` is `False`, it returns that, without further evaluation.

When it is `True`, it goes on to evaluate `x<np.arange(4)`, returning a 4 element boolean.

Or with a list that doesn't support `<` at all:

```
In [56]: 3<x<[1,2,3]
Out[56]: False
In [57]: 1<x<[1,2,3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-57-e7430e03ad55>", line 1, in <module>
    1<x<[1,2,3]
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

Answer (score 7):

```
0 < numlist < 3.5
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(0 < numlist) and (numlist < 3.5)
```

except that `numlist` is only evaluated once.

The implicit `and` between the two results is causing the error

Comment: ... which is because the `and` operator cannot be override to return anything but a boolean, unlike `&` which can return whatever it wants

Comment: @Eric could you elaborate why this is the case in an answer? That is the information I'm looking for.

Comment: oh, wait -- is it because the `and` operator isn't an operator, it's a keyword with short-circuit evaluation, so you can't override it?

Comment: @JasonS: Yes, the fact it has short-circuit evaluation is most of the problem. Note there's a [rejected PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) to allow overloading these