# NumPy general boolean indexing confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

i'm new to NumPy and i'm right now learning about boolean indexing.

Say i have some array:

```
a = np.array([[7, 2, 5], [8, 9, 10], [19, 17, 1], [4, 1, 9]])
```

I can then do the following:

```
b = a[8 > a]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[7 2 5 1 4 1]
```

But if i do this:

```
b = a[8 > a > 4]
print(b)
```

I get an error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can this be?

Comment: try `b=a[8>a and a>4]`

Comment: @ngShravil.py - no, that's essentially the same as the OP's code. Instead, use `a[(8 > a) & (a > 4)]`.

Comment: @AlexRiley your suggestion is working fine, but `&` is a bitwise and operator, isn't it?

Comment: @ngShravil.py - that's correct - for Booleans values it works similarly to `and`. On NumPy arrays `&` operates element-wise (and so for Boolean arrays it produces the desired array for indexing). The `and` operator does not work element-wise and tries to find the truth value of the array as a whole (which leads to the error message seen in the question).

Comment: *Often* if you search for the Exception/error message (`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`) you will find enough SO Q&A's to point you in the right direction. If you read enough of them you should be able to get a sense of what the message means.

Comment: Related: [Numpy chain comparison with two predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075324/numpy-chain-comparison-with-two-predicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is the `__and__` magic method, a class overrides to add custom behavior when `&` is called. `and` can not be overridden as for this any magic function does not exist.

So that is why `&` is understood by numpy array as numpy array has ability to override its behavior.