# Numpy: how do I apply masks vectorwise?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that is a list of vectors, like

```
arr1 = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 5, 3 ], [ 9, -1 ], [ 6, 3 ], ... ]
```

corresponding to x,y value pairs. I would like to set up a mask using criteria for both the x and y components, for example 0 < x < 4 and 0 < y < 7, in such a way that the mask for the above looks like:

```
[ [ True, True ], [ True, True ], [ False, False ], [ False, False ], [ False, False ], ... ]
```

In other words, for each vector in the array, I want the mask to have the same truth value for both components, and only return `True` if the conditions for x and y are both satisfied. I tried something like:

```
masked = numpy.ma.array(arr1, mask= [0<arr1[:,0]<4 & 0<arr1[:,1]<7, 0<arr1[:,0]<4 & 0<arr1[:,1]<7])
```

But it tells me "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous." Is there a way to do this concisely without using loops or if elses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the input array:

```
print(arr1)
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  2],
       [ 5,  3],
       [ 9, -1],
       [ 6,  3]])
```

You can check for the conditions on each of the columns individually (do note that [chained comparisons don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075324/numpy-chain-comparison-with-two-predicates) in NumPy). Then take the bitwise AND of both conditions and broadcast to the shape of the array:

```
x = arr1[:,0] 
y = arr1[:,1] 

c1 = (x>0)&(x<4)
c2 = (y>0)&(y<7)

np.broadcast_to((c1&c2)[:,None], arr1.shape)
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False]])
```