# How to check if pixel's hsv is between upper and lower boundaries of a color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have an opencv range for each color, and I want to check, whether pixel's range is in range between upper and lower ranges for hsv values. So, as an example, I have a pixel with coordinates x = 696; y = 260. And its hsv value is [50, 77, 174].

Also, I have a color boundaries with mask:

```
frame = cv2.imread('everything.jpg')
hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

low_blue = np.array([80, 80, 45])
high_blue = np.array([125, 255, 255])
blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_blue, high_blue)
blue = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=blue_mask)
```

How can I check if [50, 77, 174] is between `low_blue` and `high_blue`, and if that is true: `print("blue")`?

Comment: have you considered looking at the location in `blue_mask`?

Comment: If the pixel returned by inRange is white, it was between. If the pixel returned by inRange is black, then it was not between the two ranges. That is the whole point of inRange.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
pixel = numpy.array([50, 77, 174])
```

then `low_blue <= pixel` and `pixel <= high_blue` each give you a boolean array containing the element-wise comparison results.

Unlike with normal Python comparison operators, you can't chain comparisons with NumPy arrays (see [Numpy chain comparison with two predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075324/numpy-chain-comparison-with-two-predicates)), so to combine the two comparisons you need to use `&` (logical *and*, since you want both to be true).

Finally, to combine the element-wise results to an overall result, use `.all`, as again, you want all elements to be true (i.e. all channels to be within the respective intervals):

```
is_blue = ((low_blue <= pixel) & (pixel <= high_blue)).all()
```

Comment: this is exactly what `cv2.inRange` does already, which was used in the question. the question did not require replacing that function

Comment: Then I didn't understand the question.