# Filter numpy image array by multiple conditions as fast as possible

Tags: python, numpy

I need to find specific pixels (BGR format) coordinates in a game while it's live ,

(i saved a screenshot just for testing , the program it self takes screenshots continuously).

Here's a working for loop example of what i need

```
s = np.array(Image.open("image.png"))
cr = []
for y in range(338):
    for x in range(326):
        C = s[y, x]
        if C[1] < 25 and 20 <= C[0] < 25 and 130 < C[2] < 215:
            cr.append((y, x))
```

but the for loop takes **1.03 sec** , which is very slow for my task , so i tried

```
cr = s[(20 < s[:,][:,0]) & (s[:,][:,0] < 25) & (s[:,][:,1] < 25) & (130 < s[:,][:,2]) & (s[:,][:,2] < 215)]
```

but it returns me the error `IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 415 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3`

so how do i need to make it , with the fastest way?

EDIT:

example image:

[image]

Comment: You cannot use chained comparisons with `numpy`. ([Numpy chain comparison with two predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17075324/15497888))

Comment: @HenryEcker ok , i edited the description

Comment: This needs a minimal example, because I just put that one-liner in my interpreter and it did not complain, so one would have to see it failing.

Comment: and isn't `s[:,]` the same as `s`?

Comment: Best plan is to share your actual image and what you are actually looking for and also say what you plan to do with the result.

Comment: For example, there's no need to allocate and store an entire array of all locations of all variations of red pixels if you simply need a yes/no as to whether there is a red pixel in a certain rectangle. So you see, it depends what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MarkSetchell , added the image

Answer (score 1):

I would write your condition like this:

```
c = (s[...,1] < 25) & (20 < s[...,0]) & (s[...,0] < 25) & (130 < s[...,2]) & (s[...,2] < 215)
cr = np.argwhere(c)
```

The error you got is because the shape of the `s` is different than the shape of whatever you put within brackets. Other comments:

- the color axis is the last one, not the second
- `s[:,]` is the same as `s`

In the example image you posted above, I get:

```
In [3]: s.shape
Out[3]: (326, 338, 3)

In [4]: (20 < s[:,:,0]).shape
Out[4]: (326, 338)
```

that is because by setting the index along one dimension to a fixed value, you get rid of that dimension. That would have been ok, but you also got rid of the wrong dimension.

Comment: that's what i needed thank you , but i want to wait for other members to post thier answers (if there will be any) and accept the best of all

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the condition significantly using broadcasting. Let's say you have an `(M, N, 3)` array `s`, with `M = 338` and `N = 326`. All the pixels have an upper threshold of `[25, 25, 215]`. Channel0 has a lower threshold of 20 (inclusive), and Channel 2 has one at 130 (exclusive). You an express this as

```
cr = np.argwhere((s < [25, 25, 215]).all(-1) & (s[..., 0] >= 20) & (s[..., 2] > 130))
```

You have to put parentheses around the conditional expressions because they have lower precedence than `&` otherwise.

The expression `(s < [25, 25, 215])` produces an `(M, N, 3)` boolean mask because of broadcasting. Dimensions line up on the right, so `[25, 25, 215]` is treated as `(1, 1, 3)`, and effectively expanded to `(M, N, 3)`. The final `all` along the last axis reduces the mask to `(M, N)` by checking that all the channels for a given pixel pass their respective criteria.

You can take this approach a step further because you're working with integers. In that case `x >= 20` is equivalent to `x > 19`. So you only need two conditions:

```
cr = np.argwhere((s < [25, 25, 215]).all(-1) & (s[0::2] > [19, 130]).all(-1)
```

Comment: this is twice as fast than javier's answer , but what is actually happening in ```(s < [25, 25, 215]).all(-1)```?

Comment: @baronsec. I've updated the answer significantly

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `numpy.argwhere` and `numpy.logical_and`

es:

```
matching_indexes = np.argwhere(np.logical_end(np.logical_and(s<3, s>50), s !=4))
```

Comment: this one does not work exactly because the comparison is against one of the colors only, but it can be improved to treat the three components separately and then and those.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to work exactly. It was just an example to show how to use `np.argwhere` and `np.logical_and`.