# Numpy close range equivalent to `x <values < z`

Tags: python, numpy

If I am looking for a boolean array whether my array is in a close range, I can use the next code:

```
import numpy as np

vals = np.arange(10)
in_range = (vals < 8) & (vals > 3)  # equiv to np.logical_and([vals < 8, vals > 3])
```

For the upper code, I wished to have an alternative to `in_range = 3 < vals < 8`

In my opinion it looks more elegant, and it is not ambiguous.

I guess I am not the first to ask, but I swear I couldn't find and answer online. Will be glad to a reference or a new answer why this is not a good design for the `numpy` lib.

Comment: Sadly, the best you can do is [ 3 < vals, vals < 8,]

Comment: I looked for it once too without finding a solution. The core problem is that the first comparision is boolean and after that it wont work a second time. Doing it on a symbolic level is not possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17075324/12671057

Comment: Thanks @KellyBundy, I didn't search for the "chain comparisons" :).

Comment: @Daraan its a good summarize of the problem. Thanks